# Exception : Specified cast is not valid

Tags: java, async-await

**.net Maui Shell navigation :**
In a Content page I have the following code

```
private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       await Shell.Current.GoToAsync("..");
    }
```

when I click the Button I receive -> "System.InvalidCastException: 'Specified cast is not valid.'"
But if I delete **async** and **await**, I get to the MainPage without problem !!!
What am I doing wrong here ?

```
0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF in Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.monodroid_debugger_unhandled_exception C#
0x14 in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper._unhandled_exception at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:12,5 C#
0x1D in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:23,26    C#
0x17 in System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw    C#
0x6 in System.Threading.Tasks.Task.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__128_0 C#
0xC in Android.App.SyncContext. at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.App/SyncContext.cs:36,19 C#
0xE in Java.Lang.Thread.RunnableImplementor.Run at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Java.Lang/Thread.cs:36,6 C#
0x8 in Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/obj/Release/net6.0/android-32/mcw/Java.Lang.IRunnable.cs:84,4    C#
0x8 in Android.Runtime.JNINativeWrapper.Wrap_JniMarshal_PP_V at /Users/runner/work/1/s/xamarin-android/src/Mono.Android/Android.Runtime/JNINativeWrapper.g.cs:22,5  C#
```

Comment: What's the stack trace of that exception?

Comment: I edited my first post above with the stack trace (comment is limited in size)

Answer (score 0):

Using PopAsync fixed the problem for me but it was still throwing the same exception at times. Somehow removing async & await fixed it

```
Current.Navigation.PopAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
```